# How to neatly cover gaps in threshold plate between 2 rooms

Tags: hardwood-floor, threshold

We have an internal kitchen connected to our hallway with a plate joining the 2:

[image]

[image]

I’d like to tidy up where the plate meets the floor. This was previously a narrow strip of wood, but it was falling apart and looked bad.

I believe normally a ‘t-bar’ or reducer would be used here. But I can’t seem to find a good fit.

Any suggestions for an approach here?

Comment: If you use a hard material, you will need to cut the bottom to match the floor.  A soft material might be able to bend enough to match or use something that hardens(epoxy/bondo) to shape.

Comment: Are those boards (in the room the pic was taken from) a finished floor?  And is the transition at issue the one between the plate and the nice-looking floor, or between the plate and the "boards" floor—or both?

Comment: Yes, it's an old tenement flat so the boards are in less than ideal condition, but they won't be getting replaced. I need to handle both transitions, but the question was specifically about the plate and the "boards" floor (though any suggestions for the laminate floor <-> plate transition would be appreciated, perhaps a new question though..)